# C# Event Handler Issue Updating Control

Tags: c#, eventhandler

So,  here is the layout:

```
frmClient = uses frmLogin (LoginWindow) which has OnLoginEvent
```

this event is received by frmClient, and will update the statusbar (doesn't have invoke)

frmClient also uses ClassMatrix (Matrix) which has OnClientConnectEvent, which is invoked by ClassServer's event

frmClient is receiving the event from Matrix <- ClassServer

but it is showing multithreading error when trying to update statusbar

```
frmClient <- frmLogin's event works to update
frmClient <- Matrix <- Server's event errors with multithread
```

Server:

```
public event EventHandler<string> OnConnectionAcceptedEvent;
protected virtual void ConnectionAccepted(string e) { OnConnectionAcceptedEvent?.Invoke(this, e); }
```

server

```
Task.Run(new Action(async() =>.....
                        Client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", Port);

                        if (ID == 9999)
                        {

                            Guid _guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                            StageOneReaderServerStarted(ID.ToString());
                            ConnectionAccepted(ID.ToString()); // This is the command

                            GuidCreated(_guid.ToString());

                            SentGuid(_guid.ToString());

                            StartedStandardEncryption(ID.ToString());

                            StageTwoReaderServerStarted(ID.ToString());
                       }
```

Matrix:

```
public event EventHandler<string> ConnectionUpdateEvent;


Servers.Servers[Servers.Servers.FindIndex(f => f.ID == id)].OnConnectionAcceptedEvent += Matrix_OnConnectionAcceptedEvent;


private void Matrix_OnConnectionAcceptedEvent(object sender, string e)
{
    ConnectionUpdateEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection Accepted: {e}");
}
```

Client:

```
Matrix.ConnectionUpdateEvent += Matrix_ConnectionUpdateEvent;
LoginWindow.OnLogin += LoginWindow_OnLoginEvent;

protected virtual Matrix_ConnectionUpdateEvent(object sender, string e)
{
    statusPanel.Text = "Loggiasfasfasfng in..."; //works
}

protected virtual void LoginWindow_OnLoginEvent(object sender, string data)
{
    statusPanel.Text = "Logging in..."; //works
    Matrix.SentLogin(data);
}
```

Comment: I'm just confused because, the event handler += Matrix_ConnectionUpdateEvent  doesn't update the statusbar,   but the event handler += LoginWindow_OnLoginEvent does, regardless of multithread because' it is invoked on the primary thread?

Answer (score 0):

So,  apparently statusbars have .Parent.Invoke / .Parent/InvokeRequired

this works now,  took me forever to figure it out

```
 if (statusPanel.Parent.InvokeRequired)
 {
     statusPanel.Parent.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { statusPanel.Text = "fffff"; }));
 }
```